# Dismissing Modal from Script / osx 10.7+ / safari / automator / objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, safari, applescript, osx-lion

I am trying to give focus to a safari browser modal box and control its input and dismissal.

Example: Navigate to a website, it throws a modal box, is it possible to create an automator workflow or script that will be able to give the modal focus and interact with its content?

TIA,

BK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using System Events:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    click button "OK" of window 1
end tell
```

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    set value of text field 1 of window 1 to "aa"
    click button "OK" of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Ranta

Thanks much for the quick response. I see that this should work, I just dont know how to get the name of the modal window to target it. The window is a file upload window and I want to set its value and commit.

**I got this error:**
'error "System Events got an error: Can’t get text field 1 of window 1 of process \"Safari\". Invalid index." number -1719 from text field 1 of window 1 of process "Safari"'

Comment: If it's not an OS X window but part of the website, try something like `tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "document.querySelectorAll('#search input')[0].value='aa'" in document 1`.